# font awesome in android list view not working

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts

So I have created this custom array adapter:

```
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        iconFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );

        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_type_list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.EventTypeListRow_icon_EditText);
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.EventTypeListRow_name_EditText);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final EventTypeDataObj eventType = data.get(position);
        if (eventType != null) 
        {
            //holder.icon.setText(eventType.getIconCode()); f02c;
            holder.icon.setText("&#xf001;");
            holder.icon.setTypeface(iconFont);
            holder.name.setText("&#xf001;");
            holder.name.setTypeface(iconFont);
        }

        return row;
```

I don't see the I cons, I see the code in the list view like here:
[image]

**Note:** other fonts (which works on letters not icons). are working.

Is there amy reason it is not working?

Comment: use HTML.fromHtml or somthing?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: or shouldn't your string be `"\uf001"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
&#xf001;
```

is apparently an XML entity. I have no reason to believe android should treat the as such, and not as a plain string of characters. Which apparently it does, given your screenshot.

If you want to specify characters by giving their unicode value, the correct usage in java is `\u`, like so :

```
holder.name.setText("\uf001");
```

### Edit

It is also possible, if your input is `"&#f001;"` and cannot be replaced by `"\uf001"` to use `Html.fromHtml` to decode the XML entities in the String:

```
holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#f001;"));
```

Comment: I have `<string name="list_icon">&#xe623;</string>` and when I do this `holder.icon.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.list_icon));` it is working great! Maybe I need to format the string to utf-8

Comment: yes, because string.xml is an xml file, and xml parsing parses the xml entities, which textView does not.

Comment: utf-8 has nothing to do with this, these are unicode values, utf-8 is a representation.

Comment: Simply use the java `\u` notation like the example I posted when using these characters in Java code.

Comment: do you think this will work? `URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");`

Comment: a priori, `setText(Html.fromHtml("&#f001;"));` could work, although I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the font-awesome strings in your `strings.xml` and reference them using `getString(R.string.whatever)`. Android will then handle the Unicode formatting for you.

Comment: I is working like this when I add the strings manually in static views which are not listview rows, but I am getting this icon codes from database...